# Can an isobutane (R600a) compressor be safely and legally removed (leaked)?

Tags: refrigerator, gas, uk, compressor

I have a reasonably modern (but not valuable) fridge with a functioning compressor that I'll nevertheless likely replace. I would like to salvage the compressor. According to the manual, the refrigerant is isobutane - R600a.

In a well-ventilated area (say, outside) and away from open flames etc., can such coils be safely cut? And is this (intentionally leaking R600a into the atmosphere) legal in the UK?

Comment: It seems to be okay, but I only found some guy saying so in the UK.  Did not find the regulation/rule saying so.  It does seem not to be harmful, and the US EPA says it's okay to release.  It does seem like not smoking when doing it is recommended, but then I will miss the youtube video.

Comment: EIGA doesn't list direct discharge as an acceptable way to dipose of butane, they want you to burn it or recycle it. https://www.eiga.eu/ct_documents/doc030-pdf/

Comment: USA 40 CFR 82.154(a)(1)(ix) specifically exempts R600A from the handling rules. Likely the same in the UK since these laws flow from international treaties.

Comment: So, the fridge is functional but you want a compressor to play with - sell fridge, use money to buy compressor.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Your opinion on fridge disposal isn't really relevant, but I did anticipate it and try to head it off by explaining that it's not of any particular value. Thinking I might get some use out of the compressor aside, I'm probably going to have to *pay* someone to take it, not sell it.

Answer (score 2):

According to this EA post from coolingpost.com from the UK May 2014 you can just vent it as many of the regulations are beginning to relax. This is the link: https://www.coolingpost.com/world-news/us-to-allow-venting-of-hydrocarbons/

1. "USA: The US Environmental Protection Agency is to amend its
   environmental regulations to allow certain hydrocarbons to be vented
   to atmosphere. With hydrocarbon refrigerants becoming increasingly
   acceptable under US law, the EPA has announced that it is to amend
   recycling and emission regulations to exempt R600a, R290 and R441A
   under the EPA’s Significant New Alternative Policy (SNAP) programme.
   The EPA says that this step is
   beinghttps://www.coolingpost.com/world-news/us-to-allow-venting-of-hydrocarbons/
   taken “on the basis of current evidence that their venting, release
   or disposal does not pose a threat to the environment”. The
   exemption will specifically relate to R600a (isobutane) and
   hydrocarbon blend R441A as refrigerant substitutes in domestic
   refrigerators, freezers, and combination refrigerators and freezers,
   and R290 (propane) as a refrigerant substitute in retail stand-alone
   food refrigerators and freezers. HCR188C, a blend of ethane (3.1%),
   propane (54.8%), butane (36.1%) and isobutane (6%) was the first
   hydrocarbon refrigerant to be accepted in the USA when it received
   EPA approval in 2010."

There are several other articles agreeing to this but also warning to do the venting outside or in a well ventilated area but not below ground level such as a basement to be safe.